# Pandas merge have two results with the same code and input data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have two dataframe to merge.When I run the program with the same input data and code,there will be two situations（First:Successful merge;Second:The data belongs to 'annotate' in merge data is NaN.)

```
raw_df2 = pd.merge(annotate,raw_df,on='gene',how='right').fillna("unkown")
```

Then I have a test:

```
count = 10001
while (count > 10000):
    raw_df2 = pd.merge(annotate,raw_df,on='gene',how='right').fillna("unkown")
    count = len(raw_df2[raw_df2["type"]=="unkown"])
    print(count)
```

If merge is faild,"raw_df" always is falied during the run.I must resubmit the script,and the result may be successful.

[First two columns are from 'annotate';Others are 'from raw_df']
The failed result:

```
|  type  |     gene      |          locus           | sample_1 | sample_2 | status | value_1 | value_2  |
+--------+---------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
| unknow | 0610040J01Rik | chr5:63812494-63899619   | Ctrl     | SPION10  | OK     | 2.02125 | 0.652688 |
| unknow | 1110008F13Rik | chr2:156863121-156887078 | Ctrl     | SPION10  | OK     | 87.7115 |  49.8795 |
+--------+---------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+--------+---------+----------+
```

The successful result:

```
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+----------+--------+----------+---------+
|  gene  |   type   |         locus          | sample_1 | sample_2 | status | value_1  | value_2 |
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+----------+--------+----------+---------+
| St18   | misc_RNA | chr1:6487230-6860940   | Ctrl     | SPION10  | OK     |  1.90988 | 3.91643 |
| Arid5a | misc_RNA | chr1:36307732-36324029 | Ctrl     | SPION10  | OK     |  1.33796 | 2.21057 |
| Carf   | misc_RNA | chr1:60076867-60153953 | Ctrl     | SPION10  | OK     | 0.846988 | 1.47619 |
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+----------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Are the dataframes too large? it may be a memory issue..

Comment: File size does't exceed 10M.I run the script on Mac(RAM 16G),then I run it on the server which the RAM is 64G,and the result is the same. @QusaiAlothman

Comment: Could you try to find a small reproducing case?  If you use only the first thousand lines of your frame, does the problem still happen?  The first ten?  Can you drop some columns and still see the problem?  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution,but I still don't know what cause the previous problem.
Set the column in two dataframe that I want to merge as the Index.Then use the index to merge two dataframe.
Run the script more than 10 times，the result is no longer wrong.

```
# the first dataframe
DataQiime = pd.read_csv(args.FileTranseq,header=None,sep=',') # 
DataQiime.columns=['Feature.ID','Frequency']
DataQiime_index = DataQiime.set_index('Feature.ID', inplace=False, drop=True)
# the second dataframe
DataTranseq = pd.read_table(args.FileQiime,header=0,sep='\t',encoding='utf-8') # 
DataTranseq_index = DataTranseq.set_index('Feature.ID', inplace=False, drop=True)
# merge by index
DataMerge = pd.merge(DataQiime,DataTranseq,left_index=True,right_index=True,how="inner")
```